# apply style to DIV except first in line

Tags: css

We have a left nav that I am trying to tweak just a tad. Please don't critique the validity of the HTML, we have a CMS and external developers that are driving the ship and, frankly it works for now.

What I want to do is apply a style to `<DIV>`s that are after the `<DIV class="nav_selected">`, I just want indent them with some `padding-left:30px;`

Thats it, but everything I have tried applies to the "**nav_selected**" div as well which is what I dont want.  It is kind of a header, and the divs under that are children.

```
<div class="left_nav_2">
 <div class="left_nav_2_container">
  <ul class="no_bottom_border">
   <div class="nav_selected"><li><h2><a href="#">Link 1 Selected</a></h2></li></div>
   <div><li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li></div>
   <div><li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li></div>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: which div do you want to apply style to?

Comment: I love how some people ask questions and don't bother to react(comment, vote, accept) on any of the answers..

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a class for the first line, then use a negation pseudo class to utilize it.

```
   :not(/*put all the classes in your css document here.*/){ /* put the css you want for it here.*/}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work too:

CSS

```
.no_bottom_border li{
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.no_bottom_border .nav_selected li{
  padding-left: 0px;
  // or just the opposite values of the .no_bottom_border li
}
```

Is it something like that?

Answer (score 0):

ok you can use this:

```
ul.no_bottom_border > div:not(:first-child) {
    padding-left: 30px;
}
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

[Here it is which you want](http://jsbin.com/abuted/3/edit)

Add padding-left to both the divs like

```
.no_bottom_border li{
   padding-left: 30px;
}

.nav_selected li{
   padding-left: 0px;
}
```